# Feedforward from measurable disturbance

Tags: control, automation, control-theory, block-diagram, feedforward

[image]

Gff is chosen so that it completely cancels the disturbance (Gff = -Gv/P) and Lp < Lv. Is it easier to control if Tp < Tv or Tp > Tv. I am a little bit lost on how to begin here? Should I look at the gains? Formulate the transfer function from v to y?

Edit: I realized I did not state that I can formulate the transfer function Gff(s):

\$ Gff(s) = -\frac{k_v(1+sT_p)}{k_p(1+sT_v)}e^{-s(L_v-L_p)}\$

I just do not know how this helps me answering "Which is easier to control?".

Comment: What did you get taught in class?

Comment: I think, everything you have to do is mentioned in the text. Are you not able to insert the corresponding functions into the expression Gv/P ?

Comment: What do you mean by *easier to control* ? What exactly is the question ?

Comment: @Andyaka basically I got taught how to chose and formulate the feedforward filter Gff(s),  could not really find much about "easier to control".

Comment: @LvW Yes I am able to calculate the filter (edited the main post) however I am unsure how to decide which case is easier to control

Comment: @AJN That is what is confusing me. The question is:
"How should the feedforward filter Gff ideally be chosen to completely cancel
the effect of the disturbance v? What happens if Lp > Lv?
Assuming Lp < Lv, which case is more easy to control, Tp < Tv or Tp > Tv?" So basically I can calculate the filter but not decide which is easier to control.